# Query nested field with index support

Tags: rethinkdb, rethinkdb-javascript

Can anyone tell me is there a way to query nested field with index support. I created nested index like:

`r.table('comments').indexCreate('authorName', r.row("author")("name")).run(conn, callback)`

but I can't see any ways to query all comments which have specified author name - documentations says that getAll command takes number, string, bool, pseudotype, or array and filter command does not currently have an optimizer for indexes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just tried creating a nested `r.row("author")("name")` secondary index  named "authorName" for a table with the following rows:

```
[
  {
    "author": {
      "name":  "Lennon"
    },
    "text":  "c1",
    "id":  "4f66dcac-be74-49f2-b8dc-5fc352f4f928"
  },

  {
    "author": {
      "name":  "Cobain"
    },
    "text":  "c2",
    "id":  "82936ae0-bc4d-435b-b19a-6786339da232"
  }
]
```

It seems that

```
r.table('comments').getAll("Cobain", {index: "authorName"}).run(conn, callback)
```

is working and returns

```
  {
    "author": {
      "name":  "Cobain"
    },
    "text":  "c2",
    "id":  "82936ae0-bc4d-435b-b19a-6786339da232"
  }
```

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking there are might be something like query object in MongoDB but now I realized that I need to manage all index names for nested object by myself (to avoid names duplication)